# detached entity passed to persist - Spring API - @OneToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring

I am new on Spring and I'm developing an API, but I am having trouble with the error message above.

###### I have an @OneToOne relationship:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="userId")
    private Integer userId;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String password;
```

```java
    @Id
    @Column(name="contId")
    private Integer contId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private User user;

    private String ocupacao;
    
    private String natOcupacao;

    private int numReciboAnterior;

    private String name;

    private Long cpf;

    @Column(name = "dataNasc")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dataNasc;

    private String nitPisPasep;

    private int tituloEleitoral;
    
    private int numDependentes;
```

###### And I'm trying to use the controller down below:

```java
 @PostMapping(path="/")
        public ResponseEntity<Contribuinte> create(@RequestBody Contribuinte contribuinte) 
        throws URISyntaxException {

        Contribuinte createdContribuinte = contRepository.save(contribuinte);        
            if (createdContribuinte == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            } else {
        
                URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(createdContribuinte.getContId())
                .toUri();

                return ResponseEntity.created(uri)
                .body(createdContribuinte);
        }
    }
```

###### contRepository:

```java
package com.swcir.swcirsystem.Repositories;

import com.swcir.swcirsystem.Models.Contribuinte;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ContribuinteRepository extends JpaRepository<Contribuinte, Integer> {
   
}
```

###### Full stack trace of the exception:

```java
2021-05-29 14:35:23.836 ERROR 20012 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.swcir.swcirsystem.Models.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.swcir.swcirsystem.Models.User] with root cause
```

Notes:

1. I tried using @Transactional on the PostMapping method, but
   didn't work,
2. Tried using CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST on the owner
   and CascadeType.ALL on the inverse,
3. On the repository I'm using (contRepository extends JpaRepository
   ) doesn't have an saveOrUpdate method.

What is wrong?

Comment: Please, provide the full stack trace of the exception. Also, please, provide the code for "contRepository". If other classes are involved in the exception stack trace, please, provide the code for them too.

Comment: is contRepository.save(contribuinte) trying to save a Contribuinte that contains a User not yet persisted?

Comment: @MykhailoSkliar There

Comment: @tremendous7 i don't know. I'm still learning about it

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception: **contribuinte.user** is in the **detached state**, so you either need to fetch the **persistent user** by **userId**, or cascadingly persist **user entity**.

If you want to create or change user cascadingly, when you save **contribuinte**, do the following in the Contribuinte entity:

**Solution 1:**

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapsId
private User user;
```

**Warning:** **Solution 1** is generally not recommended, because **User** is an independent entity, with its own lifecycle. I don't think it is a good idea to manage user name or user e-mail with **contRepository.save(contribuinte)** method. There should be a separate **userRepository.save(user)** method for that. Besides, if UI accidentally pass null values for **contribuinte.getUser().getName()** or **contribuinte.getUser().getEmail()**, this will delete userName and userEmail!

**Solution 2:**

If you don't want to create or change user cascadingly, when you save **contribuinte**, then do the following:

```
User user = contribuinte.getUser() == null ? null : userRepository.findByUserId(contribuinte.getUser().getUserId());
contribuinte.setUser(user);
Contribuinte createdContribuinte = contRepository.save(contribuinte);
```

Make sure that the above code is in one transaction.

**Solution 2** will prevent user from being created or changed cascadingly, but you need to make sure that:

- **contribuinte.getUser().getUserId()** is never null (unless you want to unassign user from contribuinte: in this case, **contribuinte.getUser()** must be null)

For example:

- **Solution 2:** will not allow to change the user name or user e-mail cascadiingly, with **contRepository.save(contribuinte)**
- It will also not be possible to create new user cascadingly with **contRepository.save(contribuinte)**
- But it will be possible to change the user of contribuinte, or set it to null.